# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred when flushing data

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, illegalstateexception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exception occurred when flushing data . What is this and why am I getting this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327857/exception-occurred-when-flushing-data-what-is-this-and-why-am-i-getting-this)

The following is a snippet from a filter. It gets the client IP , sets the attribute and then chains the request to a servlet.

```
@Override
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response,FilterChain chain) 
        throws ServletException,IOException {
    String IP = request.getRemoteAddr();
    request.setAttribute("client IP from the filter", IP);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

The following is a snippet from the servlet which has received a filtered request. It gets the IP , stores it as an another attribute and then dispatches the request to *index.jsp* .

```
    @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String IP = (String)request.getAttribute("client IP from the filter");
    request.setAttribute("Client IP", IP);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    rd.forward(request,response);
}
```

index.jsp , then retrieves the attribute set by the servlet and works upon it.

The servlet is the first thing to run when a website *foo.com* is first opened. But as I open the website I see this stack trace :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred when flushing data
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-d6995d0c305e239e(Request.java)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:191)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:118)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.access$100(JspFactoryImpl.java:40)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl$PrivilegedReleasePageContext.run(JspFactoryImpl.java:166)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:34)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:75)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:139)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
at Servlets.FW_FirstSite.doGet(FW_FirstSite.java:27)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at Filters.FirstSiteFilter.doFilter(FirstSiteFilter.java:24)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:452)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:458)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:698)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:336)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:328)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:456)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.ensureOpen(JspWriterImpl.java:204)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:115)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:188)
... 43 more
```

Logs suggest that exception occurs  at **Servlets.FW_FirstSite.doGet(FW_FirstSite.java:27)** which is the statement *rd.forward(request,response);* and at **Filters.FirstSiteFilter.doFilter(FirstSiteFilter.java:24)** which is the statement *chain.doFilter(request, response);*.

Why do get these exceptions ?

Comment: even if the exception occurs at that point, there is probably something else done before that with the output stream that is causing it to be flushed. What that is is not possible to say with this code as there is nothing wrong with it - possibly something done elsewhere, then...

Comment: @eis I found out something regarding this. can we discuss this @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16429/discussion-between-eis-and-suhail

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your call to response.getWriter() initiates writing the response to the client when it's being flushed. For that reason, you cannot anymore forward the request, as it has been already been flushed on.

You *are* allowed to set your response content type multiple times without it mattering, but you shouldn't call a writer unless you're already done with pre-processing.

Note also that calling getOutputStream() has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the following code in the doGet method?

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
```

I haven't actually checked the specification, but I doubt that you are allowed to manipulate the servlet's response (neither by setting headers, nor by accessing the OutputStream or Writer) before forwarding the request to another resource.

Comment: I edited but getting the same exception

Comment: @SuhailGupta and redeployed too? Please then edit the question and remove the lines, so it would be updated with all the latest code. You do have all the code where you manipulate your request and response objects posted now, right?

Comment: edited the question. yes, i redeployed it too