# Filter---after setting attribute--->Servlet---after getting and setting the attribute---->Jsp How do I do this?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters

This is what I want to do :

A servlet is called.Before a servlet is called , the request is intercepted by a filter. Filter gets some details out from the request,sets them as an attribute and the forwards it to a servlet via `chain.doFilter(request,response)`. Request finally reaches the servlet. Servlet gets the attribute set by the filter before and sets a new attribute by another name. Then it forwards it to some jsp page where the page gets the attribute and processes it.

How do I do this ? I know how to write a filter and a servlet but how do I forward it to a jsp page from the servlet or is there any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RequestDispatcher.forward` method from your servlet:

```
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
          HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletConfig().getServletContext()
                      .getRequestDispatcher("/yourJsp.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

See also [javaee 5 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagi.html#bnagk)

**EDIT:** I've tested this approach on tomcat 7 examples:

- I've enabled the example timing filter
- I've invoked the servletToJsp example (in this example a servlet forwards to a jsp)

Everything works perfectly. The filter does his job and there are no exceptions.

You should have specified from the start that you had a problem and provide stacktrace, etc.

Regarding the question in the comments:

> why not request.getRequestDispatcher ?

In the example I provided makes no difference as I'm calling an absolute path. The `request.getRequestDispatcher` is useful when dealing with relative paths. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411114/servletcontext-getrequestdispatcher-vs-servletrequest-getrequestdispatcher) SO question.

**EDIT 2:**

I'm attaching the sources with the filter, servlet and jsp.

Filter:

```
package tests.filters;

import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public final class ExampleFilter implements Filter {

    private String attribute = null;

    private FilterConfig filterConfig = null;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        this.attribute = null;
        this.filterConfig = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (attribute != null)
            request.setAttribute(attribute, this);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        filterConfig.getServletContext().log
            (this.toString() + ": " + (stopTime - startTime) +
                    " milliseconds");
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {

        this.filterConfig = fConfig;
        this.attribute = fConfig.getInitParameter("attribute");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (filterConfig == null)
            return ("TimingFilter()");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("TimingFilter(");
        sb.append(filterConfig);
        sb.append(")");
        return (sb.toString());

    }
}
```

Servlet:

```
package tests.servlets;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ServletToJsp extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request,
                   HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            request.setAttribute ("servletName", "servletToJsp");
            getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
                    "/jsp/jsp-to-servlet/hello.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
}
```

JSP:

```
<html>
    <body bgcolor="white">

    <h1>
    I have been invoked by
        <% out.print (request.getAttribute("servletName").toString()); %> Servlet.
   </h1>

</html>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0"
     metadata-complete="true">

<filter>
    <filter-name>Timing Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>tests.filters.ExampleFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>attribute</param-name>
        <param-value>tests.filters.ExampleFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Timing Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletToJsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>tests.servlets.ServletToJsp</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletToJsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servletToJsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I also provide a download link that contains the example packaged as a war: http://goo.gl/GaV5w (7 days availability)

Just copy the file in your **tomcat 7** webapps directory and call from your browser: `http://localhost:8080/webapp-javaee6-1.0-SNAPSHOT/servletToJsp`. You'll see in the logs/localhost.currentDate.log file that the filter prints the processing time and the jsp display its content.

I can't do anything more to convince you that this approach works and your problem (if you have one) is in other place.

Comment: why not request.getRequestDispatcher  ?

Comment: and I have based this question on this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327857/exception-occurred-when-flushing-data-what-is-this-and-why-am-i-getting-this

Comment: should make no difference between request.getRequestDispatcher and servletContext.getRequestDispatcher

Comment: the answer to that question seems good, but it might be an issue not visible in the provided code.

Comment: what issue are you talking about ?

Comment: I was referring to your link: the answer seems good, but maybe is some other hidden issue with that question

Comment: I'll try to reproduce your problem. I'll be back to you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16435/discussion-between-y-e-p-and-dcernahoschi)

Comment: what is the reason i have been getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred when flushing data` ? I did the same as given in that link

Comment: I've provided the source code and a war archive. See the answer.

Comment: what does `/*` mean in the filter mapping ?

Comment: is a wildcard, means any url.

Comment: That means if any URL is invoked,first the filter will be called ? Be it a jsp or a servlet

Comment: This works fine with Tomcat but I have deployed my app on google app engine. It is giving a problem there. I don't know the reason

Answer (score 0):

Yes when we give the wild-card. It means that for any request the filter will 
first intercept the request. You can practically imagine this scenario in a 
full fledge web application where you need to introduce security. In most simplest
form you will write a Security filter which will authorized your user. So you can
give the mapping as generic so that for every request first your security filter is
invoked. You get IllegalState exception when you have already committed the response.
Is your code working fine? Please post your code if it is not working still.
HTH,
Ben